# PopOver on QLPreviewController is not getting Dismiss , even after going back

Tags: ios, popover, dismiss, qlpreviewcontroller

I have set QLPreviewController as A Parent to My UIViewController.

I am able to Show Any file on my View, Using QLPreviewController.

Now, when I open file to View, there is an ActionButton Sets internally,which Provides option for "Open In" , "Print".
till this it works fine, but when I click on that ActionButton, a PopOver is Displayed n then
if I Clicked Back Button, then my View is Navigated a stage back, but that PopOver Still remains there. & then My Application Crashes.

It seems to be very strange behavior of QLPreviewController.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest implementing something in your viewWillDisappear method that closes the popover before disappearing / navigating away from that controller.

Comment: Thanks Valheru for your Response :)
But It was my mistake , I just forgot to Call [super dealloc];
Silly Me :P